# alarm manager fails notifying

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have a simple code setup to notify users at specific time interval. Although the getDate method returns a future time, it still triggers right away!

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(act, NotificationPublisher.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, idTT);
notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(act, idTT, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) act.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Date dd = getDate(dateTT);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, dd.getMonth());
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, dd.getYear());
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dd.getDay());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, dd.getHours());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, dd.getMinutes());

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

FIXED date to Calendar object - 
since date.getMonth() and other methods are deprecated, I had to create a calendar object, and then get Year

Create a calendar object from date -

```
Calendar calTemp = Calendar.getInstance();
calTemp.setTime(ddTT);
```

Get month, year and other fields -

```
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, calTemp.get(Calendar.MONTH));
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, calTemp.get(Calendar.YEAR));
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calTemp.get(Calendar.DATE));
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calTemp.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calTemp.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

getDate method jjust converts a date to the system timezone

```
        private Date getDate(String dateString) {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm z");
            //formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EDT"));
            Date value = null;
            try {
                value = formatter.parse(dateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
            dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            String dt = dateFormatter.format(value);

            try {
                value = dateFormatter.parse(dt);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return value;
        }
```

I'm probably missing something obvious here, but i don't know what it is!

Comment: try removing this line calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

Comment: removing the line did not help

Comment: @Jayaram: tell me the datetime on which you want to fire an alarm.

Comment: it would be on whatever the getDate method returns.

Comment: @Jayaram : your date is having issue thats why I asked you about it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `RTC_WAKEUP` instead of `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`.

**Example:**

```
int trigger_time= System.currentTimeMillis() + 30 * 1000; //thirtySecondsFromNow 


if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, trigger_time, 
            pendingIntent);
} else {
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, trigger_time, 
            pendingIntent);
}
```

**Explanation:**

**1) ELAPSED_REALTIME** Fires the pending intent based on the amount of time since the device was booted, but doesn't wake up the device. The elapsed time includes any time during which the device was asleep.

**2) ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP** Wakes up the device and fires the pending intent after the specified length of time has elapsed since device boot.

**3) RTC** Fires the pending intent at the specified time but does not wake up the device.

**4) RTC_WAKEUP** Wakes up the device to fire the pending intent at the specified time.

Comment: I updated the code to RTC_WAKEUP, It doesn't show any notification now.

Comment: it always return a the future date and i made sure it was by debugging it